# curl as root user not working but works for other users

Tags: linux, curl, ftp, access-denied

I'm running into a weird problem when I try to use curl to upload a file to remote server running Red Hat 7.

I can successfully upload on behalf of any users except the root user.

Eg. this command works well

`curl --ftp-create-dirs -T README.md -u tester:tester ftp://domain/directory/`

But not working for root user

`curl --ftp-create-dirs -T README.md -u root:rootusrpwd ftp://domain/directory/`

The error msg is `curl: (67) Access denied: 503`

I'm sure the username/password for root user is correct because I can ssh into the server as root with them.

Comment: It's common to disallow root login for services for security reasons. If you don't care about security, you can google "<yourftpserver> enabling root login" to get examples such as [this one for vsftpd](http://serverfault.com/questions/34678/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-allow-root-logins). (note: you may be using a different server than vsftpd, and would need an article for your specific server)

Comment: @thatotherguy It's probably not a root login issue. Because I can use `ssh root@domain` and them input the password to login the server.

Comment: It probably is. SSH and FTP are different services, and there is no common configuration that allows or denies root access on both at the same time.

Comment: First comment it s correct. More, error code (67) indicate The remote server denied curl to login https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks a lot. I didn't aware that SSH and FTP didn't share configuration.

Comment: @abkrim Thanks. I enabled FTP for root user by "Edit the files /etc/vsftpd.ftpusers and /etc/vsftpd.user_list and remove the 'root' line from each file." It works now.

Comment: @BingLu I'm happy about it. Feel free to click up my comment